# display sharepoint list in asp datagrid

Tags: sharepoint-2010

how to display a sharerpoint list contains three columns in a asp data grid control.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest moving from datagrid to gridview

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163933.aspx

then instead of a gridview, you can use an SPGridView, it should do most of the standard formatting for you